# Trying to load a remote xml and always get its content incompleted

Tags: php

I have a URL that when accessed loads a XML file.
When I try to load it via my browser, it takes some time but it loads fine...the final file has something around 17MB.

I tried with the following php script:

```
set_time_limit(0);
    $url = 'http://www.remotefile.com';
    // Use basename() function to return the base name of file
    $file_name = "response.xml";
    if(file_put_contents( $file_name,file_get_contents($url))) {
        echo "File downloaded successfully";
    }else{
       echo "File downloading failed.";
    }
```

Heres the Curl version of it:

```
$nomeDoArquivo = 'nome_do_arquivo.xml';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$xmlData = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
file_put_contents($nomeDoArquivo, $xmlData);
echo "downloaded";
```

I tried via Curl and I`m always able to download the file but the contents of the XML is always incompleted.
Is there a way to do it right?

Comment: file_get_contents() might not be the best choice for downloading large files due to memory limitations. The best way would be using cUrl with a write function to save content in chunks.

Comment: Can you update your question by including the cUrl part as well?

Comment: I`ve updated the question with the Curl script that I tried. As mentioned before, it downloads the file, but without the full content of it!

Comment: Sorry to say, but I don'ŧ see any Curl in the updated question. I suggest you do the following:

- try to download the file with curl and wget command-line utilities (outside of php)
- if it downloads complete, then you are most likely running into some php limit - memory, scrip execution time or so.
- if it does not download via commandline, then there may by some sort of protection on the server side (only allowing download for certain User-agent or something similar).

Comment: I don't see curl in your code. fopen() with rb is used for reading local file in binary mode, however the code you provided seems to be trying to read a remote file. You can use cUrl which can handle HTTP protocol and allow you to read remote files. You just need to make few changes to your actual code.

Comment: You guys were right, I have updated with the right code.
I think the problem is in the remote file that are causing the issue...

Comment: @esQmo_ It seems that [php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) allows the use of `fopen` for reading remote files (and it seems to partialy work for the question author)?

Comment: @LukášŘíha You're right. However, please note that when dealing with large files or slow networks, fopen might not behave as expected. So I think cURL might be a more robust solution when it comes to this matter.

Comment: @esQmo_ OK, I agree. I just had to ask since I read your comment as meaning "it is absolutely not possible" while you meant (if I read you correctly) "this kind of usage is strongly discouraged under the circumstances and there are better tools for the job". Did I understand you correctly this time?

Comment: @LukášŘíha Sorry, I was not clear. Thanks for rephrasing me.

Comment: @esQmo_ No need to be sorry, you meant well. Actually, I am sorry if my question/objection sounded harsh or impolite. I didn't mean it like that.

Comment: _"but the contents of the XML is always incompleted"_ - meaning what, exactly? Is the XML still well-formed, but contains less nodes/data than you expected? Or does it simply get cut off at some point, leaving you with a document that's not well-formed any more?